# Command line Linux: Better Font?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, fonts, console

I'm looking for a way to get a nicer font (Times New Roman or whathaveyou) on my command-line text-only system.

That's right, I'm talking about a system without a window manager, and without X.

I'm not talking about having multiple fonts, or "rich text" -- Just to change the one and only crappy default console font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setfont` loads the EGA/VGA font tables. Look in `/lib/kbd/consolefonts` for candidates, and the man page for more info.

Comment: Or `/usr/share/consolefonts/` under Gentoo with kbd-1.15.2.

Comment: At least on Debian Linux, it's `/usr/share/consolefonts`.